# ProvisioningImportEventsCallback in TFS 2017(on-prem) when importing work item type definition

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to import modified `WITs` to a existing project. But, It was showing the below error:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ProvisioningImportEventsCallback

Earlier it was working fine. But, now the issue started.

What could be the possible solution for this? I just wanted to upload WITs through Command prompt(witadmin.exe) only. Any hints/information would help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly put the whole stack trace for people to help out.A single line of error might not be useful.

Comment: You mentioned it was working earlier, did you modify the same work item type in the same project? Could you share your command in details?

Comment: I am using same customized template for every project (around 30 projects). I am importing work items using the below command: 
cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"Collectionname" /p:"Project" /f:"Filepath"

Comment: To import work item types, you must be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group or the Project Administrators security group, do you have appropriate permission? If you export a work item type from this project and import it, are you able to import it?

Comment: Yes. I'm the Admin for long time. I've created a project and imported custom template in last week too. When I was trying through process editor, work items are importing properly. But, not through the commands.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are trying to use VS 2015 to connect to TFS 2017. Please check documentation [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits):

> If you are connecting to TFS, you must use the same version of Visual
> Studio or Team Explorer as TFS. For example, if you connect to a TFS
> 2017 instance, you must connect from Visual Studio 2017 or Team
> Explorer 2017.
>
> TFS 2018 and TFS 2017
>
> *Visual Studio 2017 or Team Explorer 2017 client*:
>
> ```
> %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
> ```
>
> or, `TeamExplorer`, `Professiona`l or `Enterprise` in place of
> `Community`, depending on the version you've installed.

You should install VS 2017 or Team Explorer 2017 to run this command. Although VS 2015 could run `witadmin` command against TFS 2017 sometimes, there would have unexpected issue.

Comment: Connecting from VS 2017 is the basic thing. I know that and I am the Admin. However I resolved the issue by clearing cache data.

Answer (score 0):

However, I found the solution for this issue by myself.

Clear the Team Foundation cache from your server and the user system from the below path:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0 (or 6.0)\cache

Delete everything from the cache folder and restart the server\system. Then Login to the server. Now, you won't get any error for uploading [WITs] using command prompt.

Follow the procedures as given in Microsoft Site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018

Comment: I don't have proper privilege/reputation to accept as answer. Please do it if you can.